# Where to find the firewall settings on my Netgear Nighthawk router?

Tags: router, wireless-router, firewall, netgear-router

I just bought a Netgear WiFi router. I'm trying to find where on this I can set the firewall settings, but I have so far failed.

The admin screen has no obvious place for adjusting firewall settings, and clicking around I haven't found any:

[image]

I previously had an Xfinity Gateway and was able to easily find the firewall settings on that. It feels weird that I haven't been able to find it for this new device. When I've tried online searches for how to change firewall settings, the screenshots and descriptions don't match at all to what my admin screen looks like. Where can I find the firewall settings?

Comment: `ADVANCED>Security` has some options.  See p40-55 of [AXF54 User Manual](https://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/GDC/RAX54S/RAX54S_UM_EN.pdf)   `ADVANCED>Setup` also has some settings. eg. page 58 for DMZ